# wpf datagridcheckboxcolumn style

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Imagine I have a CheckBox custom style named "MyCheckBoxStyle".

How can I make a Datagrid style that embeds a custom DataGridCheckBoxColumn style based on my MyCheckBoxStyle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn to create a custom checkboxcolumn

```
                                <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="gdchk" Header="Test" MaxWidth="50">
                                <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path = classname}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource myCheckBoxStyle}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't there a more "direct" way of doing what I want, I mean, whithout using a DataGridTemplateColumn? Because, in my case, I really needed to use the DataGridCheckBoxColumn column type...

Comment: The other way is suggested by @Jodha

Comment: After a massive google search on this topic, I think that's not possible do what I wanted, so I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: For me did not work until I done the following work-around:

Answer (score 19):

You can simply use your defined style with **ElementStyle** attribute.

Style defined in resources:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"> ... </Style>
```

And my datagrid checkbox column:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource MyCheckBoxStyle}" Binding="{Binding someValue}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn MinWidth="100"
               Binding="{Binding Path=BoolValue}"
               Header="Bool Column"
               IsThreeState="True">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BoolValueColour, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />    
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
 </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me did not work until I've found the following workaround:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
    Header="Skip" Width="18" 
    IsReadOnly="False" CanUserResize="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
        <DataTemplate DataType="gfxModule:BatchPairItemModel">
            <CheckBox

                Tag="{Binding}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Tag.Skip, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 

                Template="{DynamicResource CheckBoxCircleXTemplate}"
                ToolTip="Skip"
             />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```